# Tomcat v7.0 stopped to run my project at localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I was working on my web application in eclipse with Tomcat v7.0, and everything was fine.
But today suddenly I can't run my poject on server anymore.
I do as usual:
Right click on my project->Run As->Run on Server and then choose to run it on my Tomcat server, but I get this error:

```
'Publishing to Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost...'  
has encountered a problem  

Removing obsolete files from server...
Could not clean server of obsolete files: Premature end of file.
Premature end of file.
```

Does anyone know what should I do please?

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LinkedIn</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: check whether all resources are available . Also post us `web.xml` code

Comment: Try cleaning the server instance. Right click on the Server -> Clean...

Comment: well I was doing a little desktop cleaning today, but I can't think of what could I have deleted or removed regarding to my eclipse project. I'm posting my web.xml, but I haven't touched it at all (I'm using anotations).

Comment: Also, try Right click -> Clean Tomcat Work directory...

Comment: @AndreiStefan After trying to clean my server, I got the same error as I described.

Comment: `Also, try Right click -> Clean Tomcat Work directory` - did not help :(

Comment: Then I would suggest a fresh copy of Tomcat in a different directory than the one you have now and create a new Tomcat Server instance in Eclipse. Sometimes is quicker like this, than to try to figure out what happened.

Comment: Check your libraries. It might be that you have tried adding/removing JPA, JSF or something like that.

Comment: Okay, I will do that then. I will response here how everything worked.

Comment: First stop your server, then go to its `webapps` folder and delete everithing inside, do the same with the `pickup` folder, deploy your application

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled the tomcat and it runs my project again, thanks! @AndreiStefan But...somewhy, my header.jsp (header of my website, which I included to my jsps) was deleted :( Guess I have to make it again :(( A good lesson to back up my projects!

Answer (score 23):

I had similar problem, but `java.lang.NullPointerException` instead.

For me the only thing that worked was to:

1. Right-click on server instance on servers **view -> Properties -> Switch Location**;
2. Remove all published projects from server;
3. Right click on server again and do both cleans.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works after Switch Location from .metadata to Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.server.

Comment: This worked for with the original problem (i.e., not the NPE).

Answer (score 4):

Double click on server
look for server path
**delete** a folder called **tmp0** in `C:\src\trunk\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core`

Comment: Delete tmp0 folder inside workspace at : workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\ work well. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by ***deleting*** the working directory of my Tomcat server, ***cleaning***, and ***republishing***.  For reference, my working directory was:

```
{eclipse-workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core
```

And my server was **tmp0**.  I've seen other people have servers under different directories.  I found this path after double clicking on the Tomcat server in eclipse.  That brings up a configuration menu and it lists the "Server Location".

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the zip file of tomcat instead of 32 bit windows zip and 64 bit windows zip.
Add it to  **server- Window->Pref->Server->Runtime Env**

[Download link](http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.62/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.62.zip)

Apache Tomcat download page
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your web.XML file.

This error just because of web.xml configuration or 
sometime need to clean & build whole project from

```
Project>clean
```

Server clean

```
Server>right click>delete
```

Then

```
Setup new server
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can  ***remove*** these files:

```
org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
```

from `$your_path/workspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`

and **make new server again.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to a BSOD during the deploy procedure. I had a couple of corrupted files (in Tomcat config) in the destination tomcat, so eclipse could not parse them to check if a redeploy was needed.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, when I had same issue I understood that I previously commented out the Host node with name="localhost" in server.xml.

Example:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"></Host>
```

And since then I was getting this Exception each time I tried to publish changes to Tomcat.

But the problem is,
when I opened server.xml in eclipse and I removed comment brackets from this Host, saved changes and tried o publish again, I was still getting this Exception. Restarting Eclipse, deleting **tmp0** folder  in C:\src\trunk.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core did not help.

What helped is **openning server.xml in other** than Eclipse editor. It is appeared that this Host stayed commented out in it, so Eclipse did not actually apply changes unless publishing is successfull. So I removed comment brackets  from this Host in other text editor, saved changes, returned to Eclipse and publishing worked again!

Hope it will help to somebody.