# Could not clean server of obsolete files: null java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, nullpointerexception

I was using eclipse and tomcat 7.0 fine for all web application till yesterday. Unfortunately i lost my eclipse folder(which is i am running exe) and temp folder(which is workspace directory). But i have backup of that unziped eclipse folder so i past it and started eclipse to add new project in new workspace(home/xx/newtemp) and tried to run by tomcat 7.0 but i am getting "**Could not clean server of obsolete files: null
java.lang.NullPointerException**".Here i show my issue by images,

**Note :Even tomcat started and home page running in localhost:8081 but whn i add new project and run in tomcat, same error raised and nothing happen.**

[image]

So far i tried,

```
    1 stop server

    2 project -> clean

    3 project build (I had automatic build disabled)

    4 delete server

    5 delete Servers folder

    6 restart Eclipse
```

and also,

```
    Click on Servers tab and Stop the server in use if it's running
    Right click on the server again and select Clean...
    Right click again and select Clean Tomcat Work Directory...
```

and also,

```
you have to delete the .snap file located in the directory :

<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
After deleting this file, you could start Eclipse with no problem.
```

and also,

```
To resolve this issue you have to delete tmp folder in the following directory

<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core
If there is any problem on deleting this folder then restart your eclipse then again delete that folder.
```

I have tried many ways but i could not find fix .

I hope someone will help me out from the fix.

Comment: did you try deleting `Servers` project ? Select Remove from hard disk while doing that

Comment: @Arkantos yes i tried now but same error...

Comment: So the tomcat definition that I see in Servers tab is added by you in a fresh copy of eclipse, is that correct ?

Comment: @Arkantos yes you are right.

Comment: In your Tomcat Directory, Try deleting the contents of `temp`, `work` and if your old project is in `webapps` folder, remove that as well.

Comment: If it's still not helping, try the `switch location` mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288991/tomcat-v7-0-stopped-to-run-my-project-at-localhost#26206806)

Comment: i tried delete temp, work in tomcat installed directory but no use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71244/discussion-between-m-manivasagam-and-arkantos).

Comment: @Arkantos waiting for your solution...

Comment: I just pinged you on that chat

Comment: @Arkantos Thank you so much...you solved the fix.....

Comment: @M.Manivasagam What was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using eclipse Luna 4.4.2

1. Open Show View Tab from Windows > Show View > Other...
2. Navigate the Server folder > Servers and OK
3. On Servers Tab, right click on server and > Add and Remove...
4. Click << Remove All > Finish
5. Right click on server again and clean it.
6. Goto Add and Remove... again and add your project to Configured box.
7. Click on Finish after adding your project.
8. And Start your server again.

Note: You don't need to remove and recreate your servers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen to me. I found that `tomcat/conf/server.xml` was 0 bytes. I replaced it with a valid file and things started up fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by deleting server from eclipse and add server from scratch

Answer (score 1):

This happened due to a probable error in ***$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml***, which I had modified for SSL.
  then

1. I deleted the modified server.xml.
2. Cleaned tomcat.
3. Restored the original known good server.xml.

   Can now deploy and run my app, but still need to configure SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the folder (Note: Its a hidden folder so use terminal) :

**`[workspace...]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/`**

System: Ubuntu/Linux
(Worked for SSL as well :))

Answer (score 1):

today,my IDE(eclipse) happened this error,i tried all of above ideas,but it is still exist,then i uninstall my tomcat,and reinstall it, it is ok.

but...it is not a good idea.I find some files were changed  by eclipse in tomcat directory. Then,i check my server.xml in Server project in eclipse.The setting is`< Context .. docBse="webapps"../>`.But,eclipse deploy my projects
to **wptwebapps** (uh.. maybe name this,I forget it,you can recheck)in tomcat.

Comment: Odd that no one suggested to reinstall tomcat before, it would be my first try.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the contents of `server.xml` file in 'Servers' present in `project-explorer` to the one present before i.e the contents which you got after configuring the server and changing the `server.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Dell encryption, "DDPE", may secretly corrupt text files to further annoy Winturds 7 users.  Have had this problem recently with xml configuration files for both Tomcat 7 and Weblogic 12.2 on the same Dell PC.

Found junk in the end tag of tomcat/conf/server.xml.  Fixed the tag.  Redefined the Tomcat server in Eclipse. Now it works again.

Your mileage *WILL* vary.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted "tomcat/conf/server.xml" and problem was gone. 
After restarting the server, server.xml was "regenerated".

Answer (score -2):

Solution from [Eclipse forum](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409659)

and the random use of others answers, did it for me.

Comment: Why down vote? This worked for me and I posted to help others.  I did not want to take the credit from original solution and posted the link to it.