# Removing obsolete files from server... Could not clean server of obsolete files: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, tomcat8

[image: Publishing Error in Tomcat Servr]

I am creating a project which is in jsp,servlet and tomcat v 8.0.upto 
    last night it works fine but today it didn't work it gives error in    publishing tomcat server,please give me any suggestions.
    I used Eclipse Mars and Tomcat v8.0
    Actually I try to clean Tomcat Work Directory and also clean project("build/clean"), but still i get this error what should I do??

Comment: Is this helpful in solving your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288991/tomcat-v7-0-stopped-to-run-my-project-at-localhost (this popped in top 3 when I copypasted your title in a well known search engine).

Answer (score 23):

One or more of the temporary xml files have become corrupt.

- Close eclipse.
- In your workspace go to `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core`
- Delete the tmp[#] folder. (where [#] is some number). Mine was called tmp0
- Start eclipse

Comment: worked fine.. when deleted all temp files there (temp0 and temp1 in my case).

Comment: Deleting the tmp folder (tmp0 in my case) got me farther and brought up a new error message: "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component". Then I right-clicked on the server and did "Clean..." and that fixed it for good. Also, maybe helpful for others, this problem happened to me because the disk space filled up.

Comment: This did not worked for me, I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the server.xml file in Tomcat directory (/conf/server.xml) was corrupt. Replacing it with the original version worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me as well. I did not have to delete my tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Your tomcat apache has been corrupted. so you have to delete your server and configure again. I

Answer (score 1):

From the Servers view:

- right click on your server
- properties
- Switch Location

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to follow some steps:

- go to the server and right-click on the server, click on delete
- click to remove all servers from the list and press apply & save
- add the server (tomcat or other)
- start that server

You have to wait for sometime while it configure all data, finally click on restart server.

Comment: Yes this solves the problem. And Im here to find a solution without doing this because this is not the correct and effiecient **solution** to the problem.